# using java regex how can I replace all when pattern contains left parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a string that looks like this:
 `mynum(1234) and mynum( 123) and mynum ( 12345 ) and lastly mynum(#123)`

I want to insert a `#` in front of the numbers in parenthesis so I have:
 `mynum(#1234) and mynum( #123) and mynum ( #12345 ) and lastly mynum(#123)`

How can I do this?
Using regex pattern matcher and a `replaceAll` chokes on the `(` in front of the number and I get an

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near ...

exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
String text = "mynum(1234) and mynum( 123) and foo(123) mynum ( 12345 ) and lastly mynum(#123)";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("mynum\\s*\\((?!\\s*#)", "$0#"));
```

A small explanation:

Replace every pattern:

```
mynum   // match 'mynum'
\s*     // match zero or more white space characters
\(      // match a '('
(?!     // start negative look ahead
  \s*   //   match zero or more white space characters
  #     //   match a '#'
)       // stop negative look ahead
```

with the sub-string:

```
$0#
```

Where $0 holds the text that is matched by the entire regex.

Comment: Awesome!!! That worked. Also, thank you for the explanation. That was very helpful.
Now I just need to do some research to understand what is "negative look ahead"

Comment: @KT: have a look at this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html